# How can I use Python and Pandas to parse through text and return the strings I want in separate data cells?

Tags: python, pandas, string, parsing

So I have compiled a list of NFL game projections from the 2020 season for fantasy relevant players. Each row contains the team names, score, relevant players and their stats like in the text below. The problem is that each of the player names and stats are either different lengths or written out in slightly different ways.

```
`Bears 24-17 Jaguars

M.Trubisky- 234/2TDs
D.Montgomery- 113 scrim yards/1 rush TD/4 rec
A.Robinson- 9/114/1
C.Kmet- 3/35/0

G.Minshew- 183/1TD/2int
J.Robinson- 77 scrim yards/1 rush TD/4 rec
DJ.Chark- 3/36`
```

I'm trying to create a data frame that will split the player name, receptions, yards, and touchdowns into separate columns. Then I will able to compare these numbers to their actual game numbers and see how close the predictions were. Does anyone have an idea for a solution in Python? Even if you could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can get split the full string using the '-' (dash/minus sign) as the separator. Then use indexing to get different parts.

Using `str.split(sep='-')[0]` gives you the name. Here, the `str` would be the row, for example `M.Trubisky- 234/2TDs`.

Similarly, `str.split(sep='-')[1]`gives you everything but the name.

As for splitting anything after the name, there is no way of doing it unless they are in a certain order. If you are able to somehow achieve this, there is a way of splitting into columns.

I am going to assume that the trend here is `yards / touchdowns / receptions`, in which case, we can again use the `str.split()` method. I am also assuming that the 'rows' only belong to one team. You might have to run this script once for each team to create a dataframe, and then join all dataframes with a new feature called 'team_name'.

You can define lists and append values to them, and then use the lists to create a dataframe. This snippet should help you.

```
import re
names, scrim_yards, touchdowns, receptions = [], [], [], []

for row in rows:
    # name = row.split(sep='-')[0] --> sample name: M.Trubisky
    names.append(row.split(sep='-')[0])
    
    stats = row.split(sep='-')[1].split(sep='/') # sample stats: [234, 2TDs ]
    
    # Since we only want the 'numbers' from each stat, we can filter out what we want using regular expressions.
    # This snippet was obtained from [here][1].
    numerical_stats = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', stats) # sample stats: [234, 2]
    
    # now we use indexing again to get desired values
    # If the 
    scrim_yards.append(numerical_stats[0])
    touchdowns.append(numerical_stats[1])
    receptions.append(numerical_stats[2])


# You can then create a pandas dataframe
nfl_player_stats = pd.DataFrame({'names': names, 'scrim_yards': scrim_yards, 'touchdowns': touchdowns, 'receptions': receptions})
```

Comment: While this solution works on the sample data provided, you will encounter problems using `str.split(sep='-')` on actual data, since the full roster will include the players Clyde Edwards-Helaire, JuJu Smith-Schuster, Amon-Ra St. Brown, and others. One possible way to fix this would be to use `str.split(sep='- ')` (note the trailing space) instead, *if* the input data can be trusted to be well-formatted.

Answer (score 0):

As you are pointing out, often times the hardest part of processing a data file like this is *handling all the variability and inconsistency in the file itself*. There are a lot of things that can vary inside the file, and then sometimes the file also contains silly errors (typos, missing whitespace, and the like). Depending on the size of the data file, you might be better off simply hand-editing it to make it easier to read into Python!

If you tackle this directly with Python code, then it's a very good idea to be very careful to verify the actual data matches your expectations of it. Here are some general concepts on how to handle this:

First off, make sure to strip every line of whitespace and ignore blank lines:

```py
for curr_line in file_lines:
    curr_line = curr_line.strip()
    if len(curr_line) > 0:
        # Process the line...
```

Once you have your stripped, non-blank line, make sure to handle the "game" (matchup between two teams) line differently than the lines denoting players"

```py
TEAM_NAMES = [ "Cardinals", "Falcons", "Panthers", "Bears", "Cowboys", "Lions",
               "Packers", "Rams", "Vikings" ]  # and 23 more; you get the idea

    #...down in the code where we are processing the lines...
    if any([tn in curr_line for tn in TEAM_NAMES]):
        # ...handle as a "matchup"
    else:
        # ...handle as a "player"
```

When handling a player and their stats, we can use `"- "` as a separator. (You must include the space, otherwise players such as Clyde Edwards-Helaire will split the line in a way you did not want.) Here we unpack into exactly two variables, which gives us a nice error check since the code will raise an exception if the line doesn't split into exactly two parts.

```py
p_name, p_stats = curr_line.split("- ")
```

Handling the stats will be the hardest part. It will all depend on what assumptions you can safely make about your input data. I would recommend being very paranoid about validating that the input data agrees with the assumptions in your code. Here is one notional idea -- an over-engineered solution, but that should help to manage the hassle of finding all the little issues that are probably lurking in that data file:

```py
if "scrim yards" in p_stats:
    # This is a running back, so "scrim yards" then "rush TD" then "rec:
    rb_stats = p_stats.split("/")
    # To get the number, just split by whitespace and grab the first one
    scrim_yds = int(rb_stats[0].split()[0])
    if len(rb_stats) >= 2:
        rush_tds = int(rb_stats[1].split()[0])
    if len(rb_stats) >= 3:
        rec = int(rb_stats[2].split()[0])
    # Always check for unexpected data...
    if len(rb_stats) > 3:
        raise Exception("Excess data found in rb_stats: {}".format(rb_stats))
elif "TD" in p_stats:
    # This is a quarterback, so "yards"/"TD"/"int"
    qb_stats = p_stats.split("/")
    qb_yards = int(qb_stats[0])    # Or store directly into the DF; you get the idea
    # Handle "TD" or "TDs". Personal preference is to avoid regexp's
    if len(qb_stats) >= 2:
        if qb_stats[1].endswidth("TD"):
            qb_td = int(qb_stats[1][:-2])
        elif qb_stats[1].endswith("TDs"):
            qb_td = int(qb_stats[1][:-3])
        else:
            raise Exception("Unknown qb_stats: {}".format(qb_stats))
    # Handle "int" if it's there
    if len(qb_stats) >= 3:
        if qb_stats[2].endswidth("int"):
            qb_int = int(qb_stats[2][:-3])
        else:
            raise Exception("Unknown qb_stats: {}".format(qb_stats))
    # Always check for unexpected data...
    if len(qb_stats) > 3:
        raise Exception("Excess data found in qb_stats: {}".format(qb_stats))
else:
    # Must be a running back: receptions/yards/TD
    rb_rec, rb_yds, rb_td = p_stats.split("/")
```

Comment: ...and I should point out that even my "over-engineered" solution doesn't catch all the potential variations. For example it would probably be good to make sure the fields for RB contain the expected text ("scrim yds", "rush TD" and "rec", respectively). Also, what does the data file look like if an RB has a receiving touchdown? My example might be over-engineered, but it's still notional and incomplete :-)